# Refactoring duplicate rescue exception handlers in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, refactoring

I have two action methods inside a controller, that have the same duplicated code that rescues two different types of exceptions:

```
      def wave
        ...do something here...
      rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
        render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 422
      rescue Vendor::ApiError => e
        render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 500
      end

      def run
        ...do something different here...
      rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
        render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 422
      rescue Vendor::ApiError => e
        render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 500
      end
```

Can the rescue handlers just be refactored into a common private method, and called from both `run` and `wave` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) in your controller to rescue from an error in all your controller actions. You would have something like this

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do |exception|
    render :json => {:error => exception.message}, :status => 422
  end

  rescue_from Vendor::ApiError do |exception|
    render :json => {:error => exception.message}, :status => 500
  end

  def wave
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

You can even put it in your Application Controller if you want this behavior on all controllers (might be useful for rescuing ParameterMissing errors for example)

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
def wave
  error_handler do
    # ...do something here...
  end
end

def run
  error_handler do
    # ...do something different here...
  end
end

def error_handler
  yield
rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
  render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 422
rescue Vendor::ApiError => e
  render :json => {:error => e.message}, :status => 500
end
```

edit: That's just from plain ruby point of view though, maybe rails have something better in place already.

Comment: this looks like a much cleaner and elegant way of reducing code duplication, thanks!

Comment: This is much better and also usable outside of controllers (modules, apis etc.)